# How do you create a program to calculate the spectrum of a pulse of arbitrary shape?

Tags: plotting, graphics, physics, fourier-analysis

Develop a program designed to compute the spectrum of a pulse with an arbitrary shape. My current program might not suitable for solving this problem.

```
pulse[t_] := Exp[-t] Cos[50 t]

dt = 0.025;
num = 2^6;
df = (2 \[Pi])/(num dt);
Print["Frequency Range = +/-" <> ToString[num/2 df]];

Frequency Range = +/-125.664

timevalues = 
  RotateLeft[Table[t, {t, -dt num/2 + dt, num/2 dt, dt}], num/2 - 1];
timelist = pulse /@ timevalues;
fftshift[flist_] := RotateRight[flist, num/2 - 1];
Grid[{{Plot[pulse[t], {t, -30, 30}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
    PlotRange -> Full, PlotLabel -> "E(t)"], 
    ListLinePlot[Re@fftshift[Fourier[timelist]], 
    DataRange -> df {-num/2, num/2}, PlotLabel -> "E(\[Omega])"]}}]
```

Comment: If I run your code (minus the "Frequeny RAnge = +/- 125.664" in the middle, which looks like the output of your Print statement, I get two plots. What exactly do you feel is not suitable? What are you expecting to happen which isn't happening now?